# Test for zeros in [0,1] of polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm looking for a general non-constructive way (I assume there isn't a constructive way in general) to test if a polynomial with integer coefficients has a zero in [0,1]. I am aware of the rational root theorem, but I don't believe this is useful in all cases.

Could anyone point me toward literature on this subject? Or directly tell me if such a test is possible and/or what it is?

This question can be approached in many ways - sorry if I have tagged incorrectly!

Comment: The most basic approach would be to check if there is a change of sign in the questioned interval. But I think you are aware of that.

Comment: Sturm's theorem and Sturm sequences may be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem

Comment: You can use Roche’s theorem (complex and real zeros)